# How to set max height of image in UIKit 3

Tags: getuikit

I'm using UIKit 3 and I have problem with height of image in my Product detail themplate.
There is no problem with width it works just fine, but I do not know how to set max height of image.
Is there solution how to do it directly with framework?
Here is the the example:

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Ages/pen/pozYPbJ
```

Thank you!

Comment: no, you need to provide max-height for it ..and your codepen link doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry here is correct link:

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Ages/pen/rNBRmRG
```

The solution is with .uk-responsive-height

```
<div class="uk-width-1-3@m uk-text-center">
    <div uk-lightbox="animation: fade">
        <a class="uk-inline" href="#" data-caption="#">
            <div class="uk-height-medium">
                <img src="#" class="uk-responsive-height uk-responsive-width">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```